# Get rows which contain exactly one special character

Tags: sql, string, oracle, where-clause

I have a SQL query which returns some rows having the below format:

```
DB_host
DB_host_instance
```

How can i filter to get rows which only have the format of 'DB_host' (place a condition to return values with only one occurrence of '_')

i tried using `[0-9a-zA-Z_0-9a-zA-Z]`, but seems like its not right. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be using `REGEXP_COUNT` and at most one underscore is needed then use

```
WHERE REGEXP_COUNT( col, '_' ) <= 1
```

or strictly one underscore should exist then use

```
WHERE REGEXP_COUNT( col, '_' ) = 1
```

Comment: doing `<= 1` would return a string that has no underscores. You probably want just `= 1`

Comment: well @EJEgyed , distinguished the cases, nice catch, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A simple method is a regular expression:

```
where regexp_like(col, '^[^_]+_[^_]+$')
```

This matches the full string when there is a string with no underscores followed by an underscore followed by another string with no underscores.

You could also do this with `LIKE`, but it is more complicated:

```
where col like '%\_%' and col not like '%\_%\_%'
```

That is, has one underscore but not two.  The `\` is needed because `_` is a wildcard for `LIKE` patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress underscores in the string, and ensure that the length of the result is just one character less than the original:

```
where len(replace(col, '_', '')) = len(col) - 1
```

I wonder how this method would compare to a regex or two `like`s in terms of efficiency on a large dataset. I would not be surprised it it was more efficient.